# How do I remove dried spray-can paint from glass?

Tags: paint, removal, spraypainting

I used a good quality name-brand spray can of 'Paint & Primer' to paint a glass lamp, but after the second coat an 'alligator' texture developed in some areas. I followed the instructions before spraying the second coat, and the temperature was about 76 degrees.  I haven't been successful in removing the paint (the instructions say to use Mineral Spirits - but it is not working, most likely because the paint has dried). Does anyone have any other suggestions? NOTE: Scraping is not an option because of the texture of the glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lacquer thinner does a number on many paint finishes. Use it generously and out in the open, it is very flammable. Don't breathe the concentrated fumes either, being outside should prevent that.

Saturate a rag, and give it a go. Dipping is possible too.

Comment: Acetone took care of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are [citrus based paint removers](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Citristrip-1-Qt-Safer-Paint-and-Varnish-Stripping-Gel-QCG73801T/100208204) that are less harsh on humans and surfaces than conventional solvent based strippers. They take a bit longer, but are worth a try.

[image: citrus stripper]

```
 Images and links are for illustration only - not an endorsement of a product or source.
```

Comment: I tried 100% Acetone, and it worked with a fair amount of 'elbow grease'.  Problem solved.